# AOSP mirroring into local gerrit

Tags: android, git, android-source, gerrit, repo

I'm trying to mirror the AOSP code into our local Gerrit system using the bash method below.

```
#!/bin/bash

repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-14.0.0_r9 --mirror
repo sync
repo_list=`repo list -p`
repo forall -c '
if [[ ${REPO_PATH} =~ $repo_list ]]; then
ssh -p 29418 gerritadmin@local-gerrit-host gerrit create-project aosp/${REPO_PATH} --parent All-Projects || echo "Failed to create project for ${REPO_PATH}"
fi
git push ssh://gerritadmin@local-gerrit-host:29418/aosp/${REPO_PATH} +refs/heads/* +refs/tags/* || echo "Failed to push ${REPO_PATH}"
'
```

However, I'm encountering an issue within the `repo forall` loop. I have an `if condition`, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. I'm not sure whether inside `repo forall` loop bash `IF` condition work or not.

Mainly, I'm aiming to minimize multiple Gerrit SSH connections to our to local gerrit server to reduce the load.

Could you please assist me in finding the correct approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in the script.

```
if [[ ${REPO_PATH} =~ $repo_list ]]; then
    ssh -p 29418 gerritadmin@local-gerrit-host gerrit create-project aosp/${REPO_PATH} --parent All-Projects || echo "Failed to create project for ${REPO_PATH}"
fi
```

It should be `$repo_list =~ ${REPO_PATH}`. Otherwise, it's always false unless there is only one project. Even so, the `if` clause is unnecessary and flawed. `repo list -p` has the same effect with `repo forall -c 'echo $REPO_PATH'`. `$REPO_PATH` is always among the output of `repo list -p`. Besides, if there is a path `foo/bar_baz` in `$repo_list` and `$REPO_PATH` is `foo/bar`, the test still passes while it may be not expected.

Actually, the `if` clause here should be testing whether the project `aosp/${REPO_PATH}` has already existed on your Gerrit before it's to be created. First, list all the projects that contain the substring `aosp/${REPO_PATH}`. Unfortunately, it does not take a regular expression.

```
ssh -p 29418 gerritadmin@local-gerrit-host gerrit ls-projects -m "aosp/${REPO_PATH}" < /dev/null
```

And then test if one of the listed projects is exactly `aosp/${REPO_PATH}` instead of something like `aosp/${REPO_PATH}_foo`. I think it's also okay to omit the test because `gerrit create-project` would raise an error if the project already exists.

In my experience, always append `< /dev/null` to the Gerrit SSH CLI, especially when it's used in a loop. Without it, the loop breaks after the first run.

```
ssh -p 29418 gerritadmin@local-gerrit-host gerrit create-project aosp/${REPO_PATH} --parent All-Projects < /dev/null
```

Comment: Can you please help me with complete updated script?